# DWR Exception Handling on Server Side

Tags: exception, dwr, server-side-validation

There is documentation for DWR exception handling for Client side:

http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/browser/errors.html

But I'm looking for documentation for DWR Server side Exception handling. Basically the problem that I'm running into is: verbose errors(stacktrace) is returned to the client side, exposing web application details. Need to ensure no stacktrace is returned to the client.

DWR Version: 3.0

Any pointers on server-side exception handling for DWR? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like in the application, we where converting exception to dwr bean..hence the stack details in the client side :)

Comment: <dwr:convert type="bean" class="java.lang.StackTraceElement"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case I would wrap the exception with a try/catch block.
The question is: Where should you do that?

Well, DWR has a Filter mechanism which is much like filters in Java Servlet API.

You could write something like this:

```
public class ExceptionFilter implements org.directwebremoting.AjaxFilter {
  public Object doFilter(Object obj, Method method, Object[] params, AjaxFilterChain chain) throws Exception {
    Object res;
    try{
      res = chain.doFilter(obj, method, params);
    } catch(Exception e){
      // throw your Exception with no "extra" data
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

You may need to do some configuration in the dwr.xml file (which I leave to your reading: http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/configuration/dwrxml/filters.html)

(edit 1)
Some more explanation:

What this does is intercept the DWR remote call and forward the call on to the execution chain. What I added to that call (chain.doFilter) is a try/catch block; In case your code should throw any exception, it will end up in the catch block and then its up to you what to do next.

I hope this will help you :]

Comment: Basically we were converting exception to DWR bean, which was being returned to the client side for further processing. Filter approach is unnecessary.